# Scala TreeSet filter complexity

Tags: scala, data-structures

I have a `TreeSet` of Intervals (case class with start and end). If a do a filter on this treeSet such as

```
treeSet.filter(x => input <= x.end && input >= x.start)
```

is this expected to run in logN time?

Comment: The thing is that `filter` has to be a generic operation that must work for any kind of predicate. It doesn't know that your particular predicate matches the inner structure of the tree and thus can't do any optimizations based on that. You may find a better performing alternative in the answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

no it is O(N);you can see code:

```
private def filterImpl(p: A => Boolean, isFlipped: Boolean): Repr = {
  val b = newBuilder
  for (x <- this)
    if (p(x) != isFlipped) b += x

  b.result
}
```

---

use `from`,`to` it is `O(log(n))`

```
val ts = TreeSet(1,2,3,4,5)
ts.from(1).to(3) // TreeSet(1, 2, 3)
```

Answer (score 1):

`TreeSet` has O(LogN) complexity only **for search operation**.
Filter needs to apply predicate function to each element and return only the elements for which predicate function is true. Hence the complexity is O(N)

This makes sense when you consider predicate function could be anything (not just range filter).

You could use the [TreeSet.from](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.3/scala/collection/immutable/TreeSet.html#from(from:A):scala.collection.immutable.TreeSet[A]) and [TreeSet.to](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.3/scala/collection/immutable/TreeSet.html#to(to:A):scala.collection.immutable.TreeSet[A]) methods for performing a range filter

```
import scala.collection.immutable.TreeSet
val st = TreeSet[Int](4,2,3,7,6,5,3,4)
println(st)
println(st.from(5))
println(st.from(4).to(6))
```